# DATE conversion format in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server

my hiredate column is in `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` format now i want the output format in `DD-Mon-YYYY HR:MM` format..

for example :-

hiredate (datatype is `varchar`)
2018-04-16 12:19:10

required output if 16-Apr-2018 12:20.

Comment: Why are you storing dates in a `varchar` column?

Comment: while loading data into tables using import option i used varchar..

Comment: you should store as Timestamp or DATE or DATETIME format

Comment: 1. s.PI+PR existis in (t.PI+PR)
2.s.PI+PR =t.PI+PR and s.CI+CR existis in (t.CI+CR)
3. if existis (s.PI+PR = t.PI+PR and s.CI+CR = t.CI+CR  ) then s.qty  =t.Qty  ;s.find no =t.find no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @d varchar(50) = '2018-04-16 12:19:10'
SET @d = FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, @d), 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:MM', 'en-us')
SELECT @d
```

or this...

```
SELECT FORMAT(CONVERT(datetime, '2018-04-16 12:19:10'), 'dd-MMM-yyyy HH:MM', 'en-us')
```

Result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to `CAST` the field to *DATETIME*,then use `FORMAT` function.

There are three parameter in `FORMAT` function

1. Your datetime [requird]
2. FormatType for this case you need to set `dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm` [requird]
3. culture [Optional]

From your question you need to check there are seconds in your datetime.

So add A `CASE` expression to make it.

```
DECLARE @Dt VARCHAR(50) = '2018-04-16 12:19:10'

SELECT 
CASE 
  WHEN FORMAT(CAST(@Dt as datetime),'ss') > 0 
  THEN FORMAT(DATEADD(MINUTE,1,CAST(@Dt as datetime)),'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm', 'en-US') 
  ELSE FORMAT(CAST(@Dt as datetime),'dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm', 'en-US')
END
```

*sqlfiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/22a72/2*

[Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

try This

```
DECLARE @MyDt NVARCHAR(50)='2018-04-16 12:19:10'

SELECT
    InputDt = @MyDt,
    NewDt = REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(CONVERT(CHAR,CAST(@MyDt AS DATETIME),106))),' ','-')
+' '+CAST(CAST(@MyDt AS TIME) AS NVARCHAR(20))
```

My Result :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As the comments said, you should import your dates and times into `datetime` or `datetime2` column. However, if you insist on the data as you have it, this is probably closest you can get:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATEADD(second, 30, CAST('2018-04-16 12:19:10' as datetime2(0)))), 0), 113)
    , CONVERT(varchar(50), DATEADD(minute, DATEDIFF(minute, 0, DATEADD(second, 30, CAST('2018-04-16 12:19:31' as datetime2(0)))), 0), 113);
```

You could throw in some string manipulation to add your dashes for the date part of it.

Notice, the second `CONVERT` is for `12:19:31` time which shows the result gets rounded up when needed (in this case to `12:20`).

For more `CONVERT` formats check out [this source](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/).